# How to trigger ASP.NET Application Started, restarted, stopped on IIS?

Tags: .net, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.NET application hosted on IIS and I'm trying to fin a way to trigger this events in my code: Start, Restart, Shutdown.

I'm using :

- .Net SDK 4.7.2
- .Net core 3.0

I see that most of interfaces allowing to do this (IHostApplicationLifetime, ...) are note available on my configuration

[image]

Comment: Not enough to say "in my code". Inside your ASP.NET application hosted on IIS? Or somewhere else?

Comment: @LexLi Thanks for your response. yes in my ASP.NET application, in `configure` fonction of my **startup.cs** file for example

Comment: A web app touching on its own IIS configuration (like site status) is not recommended and there is no suitable management API designed for that, except the IIS REST API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis-administration/. All other APIs are for a separate management application, such as IIS Manager.

Comment: @LexLi thanks. In this case, please how can acheive some prepossessing (loading files, ...) to my Web Application ? because now this processing are happening on the first Query and not when WebApplication started, therefore, the first request is very slow

Comment: You can find tons of posts on ASP.NET 4.x or ASP.NET Core cold start, which give you various tips and tricks via search engines. None of those require access to IIS configuration.

Comment: Have you considered using command to start, restart and stop your IIS? Then execute the command from C#, such as using `iisreset /noforce` to restart iis and then using ProcessStart `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Windows\System32\iisreset.exe");`